# How to fix a folder content glitch in a FAT32 filesystem?

Tags: data-recovery, fat32

at my 450gb fat32 partition, a directory has a wrong content after improper usb drive disconnect; was:

```
/files (total 250gb)
/files/folder/
/files/folder2/
/files/somethn.gs
```

Now:

```
/files/weirЗdчname, 5 mb
```

Windows and Linux are saying that most (400 of 450gb) disk space is occupied, but sum of all files/dirs is about 130gb, so it seems that files are still there?. No write attempts since discovery;

Rejected tools/methods:

- chkdsk(Windows7): checking completed, but no changes.
- fsck.vfat: attempted to ruin drive even more (there is a lot of LFN and unicode names).
- EasyRecovery. Didn't see the target folder (maybe wrong scan options? tried best match, but not raw scan - it would take days since the drive is usb 5200 rpm..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a piece of software called TestDisk. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download It really helped me out with a similar problem.

Comment: Good tool, but no good help. Also, works bad on W7 (cant write to disk)